# How to access variable from other function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one variable in function, I want to access it from other function. I cannot define this variable out of function. I set the example code for review. http://jsfiddle.net/VC6Wq/1/

```
function one(){
var zero= 500;
}

function two(){
alert(zero)
}
```

Comment: Why not pass zero as argument to `two`? Why you can not define it globally?

Comment: can we use .get or json for this requirement

Comment: You may attach this variable to a DOM node using the jQuery `data()` like `<div id="node" data-zero='myvalue'`/> method. Then accessing to its value using `$('#node').data('zero');`

Comment: can you please set an example with data method

Comment: Hope this helps you. http://jsfiddle.net/VC6Wq/4/

Answer (score 10):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
function one() {
var zero = 500;
two(zero);
}

function two(a) {
alert(a);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make your variable underneath the `window` global variable, if this is in a browser.  So like this:

```
function one() {
  window.zero = 500;
}

function two() {
  alert(window.zero)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
function one(){
    var zero= 500;
    return zero;
}

function two(){
    var alt = one();
    alert(alt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function one(){
var zero = 500;
return zero;
}
function two(){   
alert(one());
}
two();
```

Or define any other variable globally and assign it the value of the 'zero' :

```
var zero_2;
function one(){
var zero = 500;
var zero_2 = zero;
}
function two(){   
alert(zero_2);
}
two();
```

Comment: *I cannot define this variable out of function.*

Answer (score 0):

You can declare that variable globally in Javascript and then use/modify/access as needed

```
function one()
{
   myVar = 0;
   alert(myVar);
   two();
}

function two()
{
  alert(myVar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot define the variable globally, one approach is simulate a global variable, attaching it to a DOM node, like this:

```
//note the notation 'data-'
<div id="node" data-zero='500'/>
```

To set the value:

```
   // Store the value into data var within the div
   $('#node').data('zero', value);
```

To get value:

```
   var value =  $('#node').data('zero');
   alert(value);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VC6Wq/4/