# How to access a JavaScript function parameter in another function

Tags: javascript

I have two different JavaScript functions in same file, like this:

```
function functionOne(a)
{
   if(a)
   {
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
}

function functionTwo(b)
{
   //I want to access if condition parameter a here
}
```

I want to access `functionOne` if condition parameter `a` in `functionTwo`.

Comment: `functionTwo(functionOne(a))` will pass the returned value of functionOne as functionTwo's parameter.

Comment: i don't think it works... the parameter passed to functioneOne() is local to that function... it is better to declare a common vairable and check accordingly...

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14958134/1551233) answer will help you

Comment: so i put it like as 
function functionTwo(b)
{
   functionTwo(functionOne(a))
}

Comment: You can call function functionOne two time with different parameter like functionOne(a),functionOne(b). Why write another function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function functionTwo(b)
{

    if(functionOne(b))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are the two ways....

Option 1:

```
<script>
var newVar = "";
function functionOne(a)
{
```

if(a)
   {
       newVar = true;
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
    }

```
function functionTwo(b)
{
 //user newVar vairalbe to get the value
 //i want to access if condition parameter a here
}
```

Option 2:

```
<script>
function functionOne(a)
{
if(a)
{
    return a;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
function functionTwo(b)
{
//   call functionOne(a) to get the value;
//i want to access if condition parameter a here
}
</script>
```